# C# WPF DataGrid Editable ComboBox Returns -1 as Selected Row With Single-Click-Edit

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I'm trying to obtain a cell value from an editable ComboBox in a DataGrid table. Values are successfully/correctly pulled when an item is selected from an option, but not when a user enters text into the ComboBox (Unless they double-click)

**Problem: The RowIndex becomes -1 (On a single-click text-entry), as if a row is not selected, causing the code to fail, and incorrectly handle the update.**

How can I fix this? If forcing a user to double-click is a valid option, how would I do that?

Here is my C# Code:

```
private void ComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e != null)
            {
                TextBox t = e.Source as TextBox;
                if (t != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int RowIndex = MYGRID.Items.IndexOf(MYGRID.SelectedItem);
                        if (RowIndex < 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Index < 0"); //For Testing
                        }
                        //Obtain new Value
                        string Value = t.Text.ToString();
                        //Obtain item ID
                        DataGridRow Row = (DataGridRow)MYGRID.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(RowIndex);
                        DataGridCell RowColumn = MYGRID.Columns[0].GetCellContent(Row).Parent as DataGridCell;
                        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBlock)RowColumn.Content).Text);

                        //Unrelated code continues...

                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Here is my XAML Code for the Column:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ValueCol" Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Options, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=UpdatedData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" IsEditable="True" LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I just tested your case and I can confirm that the selected item on the Grid is not being set. Have you tried using `VisualTreeHelper` to get the parent type of `DataGridRow`?

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: google `wpf find parent` and you will find a recusrive search for a specific type of a parent, once you have it then set the selected property. Then your binding will kick in and the property for selected item in your grid is going to have the currently selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing, but if you just want to read `Text` of the `ComboBox`, just use the sender dude!

```
private void ComboBox_LostFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox != null)
    {
        int id;
        if(int.TryParse(comboBox.Text, out id))
        {
            // do your thing!!!!
        }
    }
}
```

To get index you can use following helper method:

```
public static DependencyObject GetParent<T>(DependencyObject child)
{
    if (child == null) return null;

    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    return parent is T ? parent : GetParent<T>(parent);
}
```

**Usage**:

`var index = ((DataGridRow)GetParent<DataGridRow>(comboBox))?.GetIndex();`

Comment: I just tried implementing that method, but the TryParse fails on a single click, but not on a double-click

Comment: May be because your combobox text is not integer value!

Comment: I was able to obtain the string value by just doing Value = comboBox.Text; 
Is there a way to obtain the integer-value of the current row in this scenario? I still need the row index to grab  other values from other columns.

Comment: Okay we're getting there! I just now need to obtain the values in two different columns in the same row, but the method I was previously doing was using the index as a DataGridRow object, and no longer works because it doesn't reference the same object.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, but if you were using `DaraGridRow` befire then, you can use same approach as before without any issues.

Comment: I just used the above Helper method to obtain a DataGridRow object, but now the Helper function is stuck in an infinite loop for some reason. No loops were established.

Comment: @ChristopherSwierczynski That code was just for reference, it 'll for sure throw stackoverflow exception at some point just add null check (see new edits).